# What do you do when your primary key overflows?

Tags: sql-server, primary-key, overflow

We have a table, with an `auto-increment int` primary key, whose max value is now at the limit for the T-SQL `int` type. When we try to re-seed the table (because there are large gaps in the keys, nowhere near enough rows as the max `int` value), it somehow keeps getting reset to the max `int` value.

Obviously, this causes serious problems. The PK never should have gotten to this value and changing the data type would be a big task. Re-seeding should be sufficient, but it's not working!

How could it keep getting reset?

Edit: to clarify the situation, this query `SELECT MIN(CategoryID), MAX(CategoryID) FROM dbo.tblCategories` returns -2147483647, 2147483647... meaning that there are actual PK values at the min and max of the `int` type.

Comment: What is the largest value in use? My guess is that it is the maximum value storable in an `int`.

Comment: I'm clarify the post to include this.

Comment: How are you reseeding your column, are you running DBCC CHECKIDENT (TABLE_NAME,RESEED,NEW_SEED_VALUE)? Is your identity increment value high maybe, is there a pattern you've noticed in the gaps in your data?

Comment: @John P, yes we are using `CHECKIDENT` with `RESEED`, and it works for a while, and then goes bonkers again. The latest attempt reseeded to 0 and got up to 107 before going to the max again.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can "reseed" a table so that the next-assigned identity column will be less than the current max value in the table. However, any subsquent `DBCC CHECKIDENT` will reset the internal counter back to the max value currently in the column. Perhaps that's where the reset is coming from? And of course an insert will eventually hit a duplicate value, resulting in Interesting Times for the production support crew.

By and large, you're in trouble. I recommend working up a one-time script to remove/reset the uber-high ID values. Updating the rows (and all related foreign key values) is one option, though it would involve having to disable the foreign key constraints and I don't know what all else, so I wouldn't recommend it. The other would be to create exact copies of *all* the data for the "high-id" items using more pragmatic Id values, and then delete the original entries. This is a hack, but it would result in a much more maintainable database.

Oh, and track down the folks who put those high-id values in, and--at the very least--revoke their access rights to the database.

Comment: Reindexing the table might also reset the identity counter, as might other maintenance-type activities. A lot of testing could be required to identify what's actually causing the re-reset.

Comment: I would like to think someone accidentally ran `CHECKIDENT` without `NORESEED`, but it doesn't look that way, based on the timestamps in the errors logs we have.

Comment: It looks like we are in luck, and the table's PK is not used as a foreign key anywhere. Thanks to that fact, we can just start over with the PK count at 1.

Answer (score 5):

I was involved with a project that had a similar issue - though in our case, someone had chosen a field with a 4-digit number as the primary key, which kinda didn't work as we approached 9999 records...

In our case, we created a new column on the table and populated that, changed the primary key to that column, and repointed all our foreign key relationships to the new key.

Very messy, but it did work.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new table with same structure. Read from old to new (except for PK). Then delete the old and rename the new.

Comment: As Heinzi said, this would completely destroy referential integrity.